# Can't add SVN repository location (URL) in subclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, subclipse

In my web browser, I can browse the SVN repository location with `https://svn.a.b.c.net/somename/projA/trunk/Folder/`.

However if I type this identical URL when I am trying to create a new repository location in `Subclipse`, it says `Folder '' does not exist remotely`.

Answer (score 0):

The web browser is not necessarily a good test.  First off, you need to make sure you are not browsing via a specific web application like ViewVC or WebSVN etc.  The URL for those applications is not the same URL that a SVN client uses to talk to the repository.

It does not sound like your problem, but proxy servers can also be an issue.  Web browsers tend to already be configured to use a proxy if you need one.  Eclipse has to be configured separately to use your proxy.

I would start by making sure you have the right URL for your repository.  It is pretty common to have /svn/ after the hostname in the URL.  You masked your URL so it is not obvious, but if you see something like /viewvc/ in the URL then you do not have the right one.